# PHP - How to show car details on page when link clicked $_GET

Tags: php, post, get

So I am showing a list of cars, and when the user clicks the link I want to show the car the user clicked. And then display the cars specifications and images...

Take a look at the documentation, for the API: [ducumentation](https://developer.bilinfo.net/content/Bilinfo_XML_API.pdf)

My code so far: it's php so it does not run in the Snippet, but you see the code I have so far...

```html
<?php
    $id = $_GET['vehicleid'];

    $url = 'https://gw.bilinfo.net/listingapi/api/export';

    // provide your username and password here
    $auth = base64_encode("demo:ocfB6XzF73");

    // create HTTP context with basic auth
    $context = stream_context_create([
        'http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Basic $auth"]
    ]);

    // query for data
    $data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    // $escaped = json_encode($data);
    $escaped = json_decode($data); //, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT

    /*Initializing temp variable to design table dynamically*/
    $temp = "<table class='car-list'>";

    /*Defining table Column headers depending upon JSON records*/
    $temp .= "<tr>";
    $temp .= "<th colspan='4' class='th-style'>Altid mellem 70 og 100 biler i vores udstilling</th>";
    $temp .= "</tr>";
   /*Dynamically generating rows & columns*/
   foreach ($escaped->Vehicles as $vehicle) {
    if($vehicle->vehicleid = $id) {
        $temp .= "<tr>";
        $temp .= "<td class='td-style'>Bil id: " . $vehicle->vehicleid . "</td>";
        $temp .= "<td class='td-style'>Producent: " . $vehicle->Make . "</td>";
        $temp .= "<td class='td-style'>Model: " . $vehicle->Model . "</td>";
        $temp .= "<td class='td-style'>Variant: " . $vehicle->Variant . "</td>";
        $temp .= "</tr>";
        $temp .= "<tr>";
        $temp .= "<td class='td-style'>Pris: " . $vehicle->Price . "</td>";
        $temp .= "<td class='td-style'>Type: " . $vehicle->PriceType . "</td>";
        $temp .= "<td class='td-style'>Kontaktpris: " . $vehicle->CashPrice . "</td>";
        $temp .= "<td class='td-style'>Sælger: " . $vehicle->DealerName . "</td>";
        $temp .= "</tr>";
        $temp .= "<tr>";
        $temp .= "<td class='td-style'>Udsalgspris: " . $vehicle->WholesalePrice . "</td>";
        $temp .= "<td class='td-style pictures'>";
        for ($p = 0; $p < $vehicle->PictureCount; $p++) {
    
            if ($p < 1) {
                $temp .= "<table>";
                $temp .= "<tr>";
                $temp .= "<td rowspan='2' class='td-style'>";
                $temp .= "<img class='cc-images' src='" . $vehicle->Pictures[$p] . "'>";
                $temp .= "</td>";
                $temp .= "</tr>";
                $temp .= "</table>";
            }
        }
        $temp .= "</td>";
        $temp .= "</tr>";
    
     } elseif ($vehicle->vehicleid <> $id) {
         echo $temp .= "No match...";
         break;
     }
    }

    /*End tag of table*/
    $temp .= "</table>";

    /*Printing temp variable which holds table*/
    echo $temp;

    //echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: `<a href='?vehicleid=" . $vehicle->VehicleId . "'>`, then `$_GET['vehicleid']` to get it

Comment: @brombeer could you write the $_GET par out, I am a total newbie...

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Might be a good idea to create a new .php file that handles displaying a single vehicle. Use `<a href='vehicle.php?vehicleid=" . $vehicle->VehicleId . "'>...</a>` to link to it, then use `$_GET['vehicleid']` to access the value from the URL. Not really much to it. The PHP manual has a page on [$_​GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variables.

Comment: It's second page the __GET[-vehicleid], and how to del with it

Comment: @brombeer, take a look at the code in the snippet. It's the $__GET page. I get the values. But on all on them. No the one I am choosing with the VehicleId .

Comment: You need to adjust the URL for the API you're getting the vehicles from to take `$id` into account, it's up to you to find out how that is done since I know nothing about that API.

Comment: if($vehicle->vehicleid = $id) {} - this does not work as all of the cars is displayed...

Comment: Of course it doesn't, `=` assigns, `==` compares. `if($vehicle->vehicleid == $id) {}`. Please at least learn some of the basics. Good luck

Comment: That's it! @brombeer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@brombeer just issued the answer to my problem:

```
if($vehicle->VehicleId = $id)
```

// Should be:

```
if($vehicle->VehicleId == $id)
```

A small mistake with a big impact. Thanks @brombeer!